# Dynamic code generation using t4 template

Tags: wpf, parsing, templates, code-generation, t4

I am developing a WPF Code Generation tool. But after some point I got stucked. I generated dynamic code (which is basically a method) successfully using T4 template. I am writing this code to a c# class file(there is a option to select file) using streamwriter. But I am only able to do this outside the class (after the final closing brace). But my requirements are:

1. I need to write this generated method inside class iteself
2. During updation I have to get the details of all the methods listed in that selected class file (like method name, return type, stored procedure used in that method, parameters used in that method etc). In most of the class files there are 100 of methods. I need to get details of all this.

I have to do this without using any kind of string manipulation methods. I would like to do this using some kind of parsing or any other way. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Hope someone can help me on this...

Comment: Are you can add some code snippets to this?

Comment: Paste your template code

Answer (score 1):

T4 didn't provide a functionality to perform any manipulation with files.
It's target area is to produce a piece of the text.

I would suggest to generate entire class with all methods inside and replace existing file.